# How to stop message box repeating because of array?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a hangman game and to input "incorrect" if the user picks the wrong letter but it will keep repeating because of the `randomWord` which chooses the word from an array how do I stop this?

```
Sub wordGeneration()
    Dim wordUsed As Array = {"pizza", "noodle", "zombie", "object", "rowin", "running", "elephant", "lion"}
    Dim random As New Random

    randomWord = wordUsed(random.Next(0, 8))
    Label2.Text = randomWord
End Sub

Sub letterInput()
    For i As Integer = 0 To randomWord.Length - 1
        If userInput = randomWord(i) Then
            MessageBox.Show("correct")
        ElseIf userInput <> randomWord(i) Then
            MessageBox.Show("incorrect")
            Label4.Text = counter
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Exit For` after the `MessageBox.Show`... This will break further execution of the loop.

Comment: Are you saying you are after `Exit For` after `Label4.Text = counter`?

Comment: VB.NET is not VBA

Comment: Ooops didn't notice that lol.

Comment: It's keeps iterating through the word chosen and will display correct or incorrect for the letters used how do I just make it say correct once if the letter input by the user is in the random word from the array or if it is incorrect just say once rather than going through each letter individually

Comment: Adding to the original post is not recommended as your original problem is fixed. Please ask a new question with what you have tried and what is wrong that way every one can see and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler and faster to let VB do the search for you.

```
Sub letterInput()
    if InStr(randomWord.Length, userInput) > 0
        MessageBox.Show("correct")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("incorrect")
        Label4.Text = counter
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: I am assuming userInput is a single character.